# Show that $\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)=0$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ be a real-valued, bounded, twice differentiable function defined on $(0,\infty)$
with $f'(x) \geq 0$ and $f''(x) \leq 0$. Show that $\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)=0$.

Comment: If a given $f(x)$ satisfy the conditions then so does $f(x)+c$ for any constant $c$. Thus there is no unique limiting value.

Comment: Did you perhaps mean show that the limit exist and is finite ? That would at least make the statement true (and we dont even need the second derivative condition)

Answer (score 4):

The function

$$f(x)=\frac x{x+1}\;$$

is a counterexample.

Comment: @KimJongUn, your example isn't bounded in $\;(0,\infty)\;$ .

Comment: Good point. I was careless, focusing on just large $x$. I will delete it. Thanks.

Comment: We can do it simpler: $f(x)=1$

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps I've misunderstood something here, but
$$f(x)=\arctan x \implies f^\prime(x) = \frac{1}{1+x^2} \implies f^{\prime\prime} = -\frac{2x}{(x^2+1)^2}$$
Then $f^{\prime\prime} \le 0$, $f^\prime(x) \ge 0$ and $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = \tfrac{\pi}{2}$.

So it seems a bit hard to prove given that there is a counter-example.